# SQL Issues With Different Select Statements that are Grouped together

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am  having difficulties addressing this query I am putting together. I have one table
called KpiSetupOee with Column names as OeeID, FkEquipmentType, Nominal, Low.

[image]

I have a select statement that gives me the Nominal value where FkEquipmentType is equal to ‘WM’

```
Select * from KpiSetupOee where FkEquipmentType =’WM’
```

Then I want to combine another select statement to retrieve the lowest Nominal value other than where FkEquipmentType <> ‘WM’

```
Select top 1 * from KpiSetupOee where FlEquipmentType <>’WM’ Order by Nominal asc
```

When I run this separately I get the right answers for both select statements. When I do a union all in the middle, I get the right answer for the first statement but the wrong answer for the second. The second select is not giving me the lowest Nominal  value. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong? Is there an easier query to do that will get me these values? It doesn’t matter which select statement goes first. I just need the values (Nominal, Low) where the equipment type is ‘WM’ and where the lowest Nominal value of the rest when the equipment type does not equal WM. Any suggestions? Thanks for any help

```
Select * from KpiSetupOee where FkEquipmentType =’WM’
Union all
Select top 1 * from KpiSetupOee where FlEquipmentType <>’WM’ Order by Nominal asc
```

Comment: Put your 2nd `SELECT` inside brackets: `(SELECT ... )`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with a query as such:

```
SELECT TOP 2 * FROM (Select 1 as 'RowNum', OeeID, FkEquipmentType, Nominal, Low from #KpiSetupOee where FkEquipmentType ='WM'
Union
Select 2, OeeID, FkEquipmentType, Nominal, Low from #KpiSetupOee where FkEquipmentType <> 'WM') A Order by 'RowNum', Nominal asc
```

The benefit of this method is that it will always ensure the row having `FkEquipmentType` as 'WM' is always the first row in the return query.

See this here-> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e39f6/1 and http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/656a2/1

Hope this helps!!!

Comment: Yes, this worked well, thank you. Any reason why I lost points for asking a question?

Comment: @ENGR024 Someone must have downvoted your question. You lose reputation when someone downvotes your question and gain reputation when someone upvotes it!!!

Answer (score 3):

Instead try your query like below by wrapping the `select` in `()`

For MySQL the syntax would be as below. See this fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/18ab2/2

```
(Select * from tab1 where FkEquipmentType = 'WM')
Union all
(Select * from tab1 where FkEquipmentType <> 'WM' 
 Order by Nominal asc limit 1);
```

For SQL Server the syntax would be as below. see here for demo http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/18ab2/11

```
Select oeeid, FkEquipmentType,nominal,low
from tab1 where FkEquipmentType ='WM'
Union all
select oeeid, FkEquipmentType,nominal,low 
from
  (
  Select *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY nominal) as rn from tab1 
  where FkEquipmentType <> 'WM' 
  ) X where rn = 1;
```

Comment: This query won't compile in `SQLServer` or `MySQL` for that matter. Could you make a fiddle to show that this does work?

Comment: I tried it to, I couldn't get it working. The answer below it works well.

Comment: @SatwikNadkarny, syntax given was for MySQL since question was tagged with MySQL and it indeed the corect synatx which works pefectly in MySQL; only hick was that I didn't taken care of the `top 1` which should be conerted to `limit 1`. Anyways, current edit would make much more sense.

Comment: @ENGR024, your qustion was tagged wih both MySQL and SQL Server. So the answer I given was on MySQL syntax. there was a small mistake present. mind trying again ... see edited answer.

Comment: Rahul, It was my mistake thinking MySQL and SQL Server would have the same syntax. Sorry to anyone for the confusion.